# Running an executable on Mac without giving permissions to all Unidentified Developers

Tags: macos, security, permissions, xattr

Mac does not allow users to run files from Unidentified Developer to save the users. But now if you know that it was built by your colleague then you can run it.

One of the ways to do this would be to allow apps to be run from Unidentified Developer
[image: This permissions will make you vulnerable]

Alternatively you can run it everytime by clicking allow - which cannot be done when you are running it from a script!

Comment: Clearly this was intended to be a self-answered question. However, self-answered questions have to meet the same criteria as any other question. They have to a) be on-topic for this site; and b) they must meet the same quality standards as any other question. This question as written doesn't meet either of those requirements. It's a general computing question ("How do I run software from an Unidentified Developer on my Mac?"), and it's not a clear and specific programming related question. If the question was improved, bot it and the answer might be suitable for posting on [apple.se] instead.

Comment: Can you give more specific comments what can be added?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Mac sets the xtended attributes and disables executing the file. You can see them using

```
ls -le <filename>
-rw-r--r-x@ ... more details
xattr -l <filename>
com.apple.quarantine: <Some Values>
```

Remove the xtended attributes

```
xattr -d com.apple.quarantine <filename>
```

Grant execute permissions!

```
chmod 744 <filename>
```